# C++ list of pointers goes out of scope without 'new'

Tags: c++, list, pointers, scope

I'm fairly new to C++ and writing a bank project to practice. I'm using a list to hold pointers of type `bank_account`, which has members `first_name`, `last_name`, and `balance`. After adding an entry to the list I am attempting to get the element I added, but by the time I reach the `get()` method, the names no longer exist. I think it's because the pointers go out of scope and may be destructed when they leave the loop.

The get method in `bank.cpp:`

```
bank_account* bank::get(const string &f_name, 
                        const string &l_name, 
                        const int &account_number) 
{
    for (auto it = bank::accounts.begin(); it != bank::accounts.end(); it++){
        bank_account curr_ba = **it;    //dereference twice
        std::cout << "Curr fname: " << curr_ba.first_name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Curr lname: " << curr_ba.last_name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Acct num: " << curr_ba.acct_num << std::endl;
        if (curr_ba.get_first_name() == f_name && 
             curr_ba.get_last_name() == l_name && 
             curr_ba.get_account_number() == account_number) {
            return *it;//dereferences the pointer, which leaves another pointer
    }
}
```

In `main.cpp:`

```
bank bank;
while(more_user_input){
    //get first_name and last_name, assign account_number
    bank_account ba(first_name, last_name);
    bank_account *ba_ptr = &ba;
    bank.add_acct(ba_ptr);
    //Withdraw and deposit amts, add more people, etc. 
}
//get first name, last name, account number of desired person
bank_account *ba = (bank.get(f_name, l_name, acct_number));
```

This prints: 
`Curr fname:`, `Curr lname:`, `Acct num: some #` for every entry as if `fname` and `lname` have been destructed (I provided no destructor -- the default is used). The account number is maintained. However, if I change these two lines in `main.cpp:`

```
bank_account ba(first_name, last_name);
bank_account *ba_ptr = &ba;
```

to

```
bank_account *ba_ptr = new bank_account(first_name, last_name);
```

it works and I find the element, but I am confused about why. I know `new` adds things to the heap rather than the stack, could that be part of why the pointers in the list seem to go out of scope? Aside from the fact that a `vector` is a better idea for lots of accessing and that I didn't `delete` the pointer in my example (and should be using smart pointers), if anyone could shed some light on why one works and the other doesn't, I'd really appreciate it. Am I right about the destructor being called on the pointers in the list in the first case?

Comment: You're creating the object locally to the scope of the `while` loop. Each time the loop iterates, a new local scope is created, and all objects from the previous iteration are destroyed.

Comment: In general, you can't access automatic objects after the block where they were declared is exited.

Comment: "*I think it's because the pointers go out of scope and [the objects] may be destructed when they leave the loop*" - that is exactly what happens.  You shouldn't store `bank_account*` pointers in the list at all, store actual `bank_account` objects instead. Or, if you really need pointers, store `std::unique_ptr<bank_account>` objects, which requires allocating the `bank_account` objects in dynamic (heap) memory instead of automatic (stack) memory. Using `new` solves your problem because the objects don't go out of scope until you `delete` them (or let `std::unique_ptr` do it for you).

Comment: Don't use `new` and pointers until you are applying for your Guru certification. If you think you need a pointer, you probably don't. But if you do, use std::make_unique. (But you don't.)

Comment: @Barmar so is it not possible to add objects to a list in a loop and be able to access them later?

Comment: @Harpagornis Not if you're storing pointers to them, because the address becomes invalid when you leave the loop. You can do it if you store the objects themselves, which makes a copy.

Comment: @Barmar got it, thanks!